# Windows 8.1 forces PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE?

Tags: windows, winapi, manifest, dpi, highdpi

I'm trying to set the DPI awareness level dynamically at run-time (for testing/debugging purposes).

This works perfectly on Windows 8.0. When I build without a `dpiAware` node in the manifest I can control it by calling/skipping `SetProcessDPIAware` early in WinMain. I can also control it by specifying `true` or `false` in the `dpiAware` node in the manifest.

Windows 8.1 is another story. I can get `PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE` by calling `SetProcessDPIAware` or by specifying `true` in the manifest but I cannot seem to get `PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE`!

Specifying `false` in the manifest seems to have no effect and Process Explorer reports my application as Per-Monitor aware!

Even stranger is that calls to `SetProcessDpiAwareness()` does not respect the `PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE` parameter while `PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE` works correctly.

A simple example application that only links to kernel32 and shcore will jump directly from `PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE` to `PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE` even when the parameter is `PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE`:

```
... WinMain(...)
{
  Sleep(1000*20); // Process Explorer reports me as Unaware at this point. (user32 is not loaded)
  SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE);
  Sleep(1000*20); // Process Explorer now reports me as Per-Monitor aware! (user32 is now loaded)
  return 0;
}
```

SetProcessDpiAwareness is new in Windows 8.1 and [MSDN just says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302122(v=vs.85).aspx) "Possible values are from the PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS enumeration".

Is it not possible to turn off DPI awareness with `PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE` and/or dpiAware `false` in Windows 8.1?

Comment: SetProcessDpiAware is deprecated, the new function is SetProcessDpiAwareness. And note that "This API fails if the DPI awareness is specified in the application manifest".

Comment: @JonathanPotter Did you even read the question? How could I be talking about PROCESS_*_AWARE if I did not know about this API? I know SetProcessDPIAware is deprecated (but it works correctly and gives you the expected PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE). My question is; why does SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE) not work. I have tried to get PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE on Windows 8.1 by using just the API or just a manifest and neither seem to work.

Comment: What is the actual return value of `SetProcessDpiAwareness()`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau S_OK for all 3 enum values. (And there seems to be one undocumented exception where it does not return the expected access denied: first call `SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE)` and then `SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE)`, both will succeed and you end up @ PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE)

Comment: SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE) seems to work correctly in Win10TP so maybe it is just a bug in 8.1?

Comment: Found the same problem, there appears to be no MSDN documentation supporting the behavior.